# finding words that contain no vowels from a text file

Tags: c

Good day all, I am very new to the c programming language and am having a bit of trouble with some code I am working on. My task is to loop through a a text file containing several thousand words and locate the words that contain no vowels. I have been able to read the text file and print out all of the words but have been unsuccessful in locating the words with no vowels. When I run my code I either get all of the words or I get no output and I am unsure why. Any help I could receive would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 64


int main()
{
     FILE* f = fopen("test.txt", "r");

  char word[MAX_LENGTH];
  int length = strlen(word);
  int i;


  while (fgets(word, MAX_LENGTH, f)) {

        for (i = 0;  i<length; i++){
            if(word[i] == 'a' | word[i] == 'e'|
               word[i] == 'i' | word[i] == 'o'|
               word[i] == 'u' | word[i] == 'y'){
                   break;
            }//end of if statement
            else{
                printf("%s ", word);
        }//end of else
        }//end of for loop
}//end of while loop
}//end of main`
```

Comment: The logic for testing if a word contains vowels is not right i guess.

Comment: What's the text file format? Each line contains a word or something like all words in a single line separated by spaces?

Comment: Word is the total string you can not print it all. Ok, I am coming with my answer.

Comment: `||` instead of `|` has the advantage of short-circuit evaluation, btw...

Comment: Besides the comment by Muhammad and mafso `length = strlen(word);` needs to be inside the while not outside.

Comment: the file type that is being read is a text file with one word on each line, no spaces r comas . The file contains about 5000 words. in the book that I am using the example that was given only used the single pipe, I was not aware there was a difference between the two. Thank you

Comment: I have provided a much simpler solution to your 1 word per line request that wasn't made apparent in the original question. I appended it to the end of my previous answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code takes a different approach. It will use `fgets` to read each line in but then uses `sscanf` to find each word in the string. This should handle tabs and spaces between words. It also makes sure we don't overflow the input buffer if a line is too long. If a line is too long `fgets` will fill the string buffer with what it found. We must make sure we skip past all the remaining characters up to the newline `\n` so that we will properly find the beginning of the next line.

The code also fixes a few issues. The string length was being set in the original poster's (OP) code in the wrong place. The bitwise `|` has been changed to logical or `||` and the code has been modified to search for vowels in a word and set a flag if one is found. If a word doesn't contain a vowel it is printed out. The code should work under a C89 compiler (or later).

Information on using `sscanf` to parse a character string can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 512
#define MAX_WORD_LENGTH MAX_LINE_LENGTH

int
main()
{
    FILE *f = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

    /* Process each line in the file */
    while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, f)) {
        char word[MAX_WORD_LENGTH];
        char *curline = line;   /* current pointer in the string we are processing */
        int charsread;

        /* If we read maximum number of characters then make
         * sure we flush the rest of the line up until the newline so
         * the next pass will start at the beginning of the next line */
        if ((line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH - 1] != '\0')
            && (line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH - 1] != '\n')) {
            while (fgetc(f) != '\n');
        }

        /* Scan for each word in the string we read */
        while (sscanf(curline, "%s%n", word, &charsread) > 0) {
            int i;
            int wordlen = strlen(word);
            int vowelfnd = 0;   /* vowelfnd set as false */

            for (i = 0; i < wordlen; i++) {
                if (word[i] == 'a' || word[i] == 'e' ||
                    word[i] == 'i' || word[i] == 'o' || 
                    word[i] == 'u' || word[i] == 'y') {
                    /* Set vowelfnd to true */
                    vowelfnd = 1;
                    break;
                } /* end of else */
            } /* end of for loop */

            /* If we didn't find a vowel print word */
            if (!vowelfnd)
                printf("%s ", word);

            /* Advance past the word we just read in the
             * string buffer */
            curline += (charsread);
        }
    } /* end of while loop */
    return 0;
} /* end of main */
```

A more advanced method of reading words from a string (the one I would use) would be to use the `strtok` C function which you can find more about [here](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino_lib_ref%2Fs%2Fstrtok.html). The link also contains some sample code that can be used to search for words in a string. One advantage to strtok is that you can easily specify other word delimiters like periods, question marks etc.

It appears after the OP posted the question they added an additional piece of information. All the solutions provided have assumed that there are multiple words to a line however that is not the case. The simplest solution then is to fix the bugs in the original to simply be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 64

int
main()
{
    FILE *f = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    char word[MAX_LENGTH];
    int i;
    int length;

    while (fgets(word, MAX_LENGTH, f)) {
        int vowelfnd = 0; /* Vowel found false */

        /* Remove the end of line character(s) */
        strtok(word, "\n");

        length = strlen(word);

        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (word[i] == 'a' || word[i] == 'e' || word[i] == 'i' ||
                word[i] == 'o' || word[i] == 'u' || word[i] == 'y') {
                vowelfnd = 1;   /* Vowel found true */
                break;
            } /* end of if statement */
        } /* end of for loop */

        if (vowelfnd)
            printf("%s ", word);

    } /* end of while loop */

    return 0;
} /* end of main */
```

Comment: Thank you for the links to strtok and sscanf. Being new to c I am totally unaware of these functions. After reading through your corrections and additions I am understand a bit better. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I see you removed it as accepted response. Did it have a problem that I can correct?

Comment: I also see after I posted this answer you actually amended your question (in a followup comment) stating something new - that each word is on a line by itself. This was left out of your question. In fact if that is the case there is a far simpler solution than the one I posted and the one you accepted. Had you asked the right question I could have given you a better answer at that time.

Comment: Michael I am sorry I inadvertently un-selected your response. Your answer provided me with the information I needed. I have re-selected your answer and please accept my apologizes. I was confused and thought I was giving credit to all of the responses that helped me out.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 64


int main()
{
 FILE* f = fopen("test.txt", "r");

      char word[MAX_LENGTH];
      int length = strlen(word);
      int i,j,k,flag=0;


      fgets(word, MAX_LENGTH, f);

            for (i = 0;  i<length; i++)
            {
                 if(word[i]==" ")
                  {
                   flag=0;
                   j=i;
                   for(k=i;word[k]!=" ";k++)
                     {
                        if(word[i] == 'a' | word[i] == 'e'|
                        word[i] == 'i' | word[i] == 'o'|
                        word[i] == 'u' | word[i] == 'y')
                         {
                            flag=1;
                            break;
                         }//end of if statement
                     }
                if(flag==0)
                for(i=i;i<=k;i++) printf("%c",word[i]);
                  }
              }//end of for loop 
}
```

Comment: Do you understand masfo's comment to the question?

Comment: Thank's but I find but did not see Masfo's comment here @James Morris

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the line length=strlen(word), between while and for.

Comment: That is only one of a multitude of issues. You need to do that, you should change bitwise `|` to `||` (for efficiency) and you need to read single words from the file not complete strings via `fgets` or if you use `fgets` you need to break the resulting string into component words before processing.